# How to play sounds asynchronuously, but themselves in a queue?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, asynchronous

I just want to play 4 sounds after each other (sounds1->sound2->sound3), but without stopping the flow in my code during each play or without waiting for each sound to finish.

I have searched for this about everywhere, but every direction I read, gets stuck in some other problem.

My best bet so far was: using my already used SoundPlayer from System.Media and make my own queue function, but Soundplayer doesn't have a "finished playing" event so I have no idea of knowing when to start the next sound.  (Really, Microsoft?)

Other solution and problems:
DirectSound seems complicated to get working in .NET (c#).
Win Playsound doesn't really help because it can't queue either.

Comment: You could call `PlaySync()` in a background thread.

Comment: NAudio has a `PlaybackStopped` event... it also might have a built-in queue; I'm not too familiar with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use **PlaySync on a thread outside UI**, eg: Background thread, as some people have commented.

Here is a sample (untested) **using a thread-safe* BlockingCollection for the queue**
   * *which you can use in and outside the thread*

You may want to make your own class or methods that rises an event every time the sounds ends. Or you can just loop the queue in the thread since PlaySync will just wait by itself.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
namespace PlaySound
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Thread soundPlayThread;
        private BlockingCollection<string> speakQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>();
        private CancellationTokenSource cancelSoundPlay;
        private int soundPlayCount = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cancelSoundPlay = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }

        private void btnStartSoundPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartSoundPlay();
        }

        private void btnStopSoundPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cancelSoundPlay.Cancel();
            Console.WriteLine("Sound play cancelled.");
        }

        private void btnAddToQueue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            speakQueue.Add("MyFile.wav");
        }

        private void queueAndPlay(string loc)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(loc=loc+".wav"))
                loc=configPath+"soundnotfound.wav";
            speakQueue.Add(loc);
            StartSoundPlay();
        }


        private void StartSoundPlay()
        {
            //Sound Player Loop Thread
            if (this.soundPlayThread == null || !this.soundPlayThread.IsAlive)
            {
                this.soundPlayThread = new Thread(SoundPlayerLoop);
                this.soundPlayThread.Name = "SoundPlayerLoop";
                this.soundPlayThread.IsBackground = true;
                this.soundPlayThread.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Sound play started");
            }
        }
        //Method that the outside thread will use outside the thread of this class
        private void SoundPlayerLoop()
        {
            var sound = new SoundPlayer();
            foreach (String soundToPlay in this.speakQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable(cancelSoundPlay.Token))
            {
                //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playsync.aspx
                speaker.SoundLocation=soundToPlay;
                //Here the outside thread waits for the following play to end before continuing.
                sound.PlaySync();
                soundPlayCount++;
                Console.WriteLine("Sound play end. Count: " + soundPlayCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```